# capturing function call as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

using JS; I am passing a function name as an optional argument. I would like to make a switch case that reads the functions name that is being passed. How would I capture the functionVariable as if it were a string "functionVariable"?

Example:

```
function test(functionVariable)
{
  switch(functionVariable)
  {
    case firstFunction:
    alert('1st');
    break;

    case secondFunction:
    alert('2nd');
    break;
  }
}
```

When I alert functionVariable, it prints the whole function. It makes sense why but I'm trying to work around it and just get the functions name.

***EDIT***
Working example

```
function test(functionVariable)
{
  switch(functionVariable.name)
  {
    case firstFunction:
    alert('1st');
    break;

    case secondFunction:
    alert('2nd');
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).

```
function doSomething() {
  // does something
}
console.log(doSomething.name); // "doSomething"
```

Note that this only works for function declarations and named function expressions. Unnamed function expressions won't work.

```
var getA = function getA() {
};
console.log(getA.name); // "getA"

var getB = function() { // Notice the lack of a name
};
console.log(getB.name); // ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `functionVariable.name`, here is an example:

```
x = function test() {}
console.log(x.name)
// logs "test"
```

Comment: answer is correct but other guys will be more informative to the next guy. Thank you